# A basic question about command-line

Tags: command-line-interface

Here is the line I met.

```
 IF /I "" NEQ "[parameter]" ...//,then whatwhat
```

coud anyone would like to give me some explaination of '/i' here?   Or give me some suggestion or link so that I can learn something about it myself.

Comment: **Which operating system???**

Comment: @mailq: It's clearly BeOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/I` says to do case insensitive string comparisons. You can use the built in help system on windows machines to get information.

```
HELP IF
```